# Can I create an instance manually when I have to use Hilt as dependency injection?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I use Hilt as dependency injection in my project.

The `ObjectModule` module provides the instance of `MediaRecorder`, so I can use it in both `SoundViewModel` and `HandleMeter`.

In order to release resources, I have to assign `null` to `mRecorder` in `fun stop()` of `SoundViewModel`, so I need to create an instance of `MediaRecorder` in `fun play()` as needed.

1:  Do I need create the instance using `mRecorder =  MediaRecorder()` by myself?  Can I get it from dependency injection ?

2:  Will the instance of `MediaRecorder` in `class HandleMeter @Inject constructor(val mRecorderFromDI: MediaRecorder)`  be recreated by dependency injection again when I have created it using `mRecorder =  MediaRecorder()`  in `fun play()` ?

```
@HiltViewModel
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val aHandleMeter: HandleMeter,
    private var mRecorder: MediaRecorder?
 ): ViewModel() {

    fun play() {
        //In order to handel re-play, so I write the following code.
        if (mRecorder==null) {
            mRecorder =  MediaRecorder()  //Do I need create by myself? Can I get it from dependency injection ?
        }
        
        mRecorder?.let {
            with(it) {
                setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                 ...
                prepare()
                start()
            }
        }

        val my= aHandleMeter.getMSoundDensity() 
        ...
    }
    
    fun stop() {
        try {          
            mRecorder?.stop()    
            mRecorder?.release()
            mRecorder = null
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
    }  
 
}


@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object ObjectModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMediaRecorder(): MediaRecorder {
        return  MediaRecorder()
    }
}


class HandleMeter @Inject constructor(val mRecorderFromDI: MediaRecorder): IHandleMeter {

    override fun getMSoundDensity(): Flow<MSoundDensity> {
      val temp = mRecorderFromDI.maxAmplitude
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create the instance manually and you can also get that from your Dependency injection. There is no difference as both will return a new instance.
2. No, the instance is not recreated by Dependency injection when you do `mRecorder =  MediaRecorder()`. You actually lose reference to initial instance created by dependency injection and get a new instance of `MediaRecorder()` assigned to `mRecorder`.

Comment: Thanks! But I find the object `mRecorderFromDI` in class  `HandleMeter` point to previous address after `mRecorder =  MediaRecorder()` is launched  in `fun play()`, it will cause error, how can I fix it?

Comment: Yes, `mRecorderFromDI` will still be pointing to the old instance because all these variables point to that same **Singleton** instance from DI. However, in you `fun stop()` you are releasing your value and resources from that **Single Instance**. Hence, you will get the error. To avoid that, you should **NOT** Clear/Release your values you are going to need in other places of your code